# Updating AVPlayerItem video composition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem, avvideocomposition

Me and my team are stuck on an issue for a few days now.

We have `AVPlayer` which plays `AVPlayerItem` with a custom `AVVideoComposition`.

```
player.currentItem?.videoComposition = getUpdatedVideoComisition()
```

The user can decide if to remove or keep the composition. I'm trying to remove the composition by calling

```
player.currentItem?.videoComposition = nil
```

But in an unexpected way even when assigning nil to the `videoComposition` property, it's keep on playing with the same composition.

**How can we remove the `AVVideoComposition` without switching `AVPlayerItem`?**

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Best Regards,
Roi and the team

Comment: It seems like you will have to switch AVPlayerItem. Why do you want to avoid doing so?

Comment: @ThanhPham It generate the UI to flicker a lot more than just switching AVPlayerItem.. But I think that's the way to go

Comment: @RoiMulia Any luck?

Comment: @mehdok Not really, we decide to switch items..